# Template inheritance with strings

Tags: go

I have a few small .html files that I parse like:

```
template.Must(
    template.New("test").
        ParseFiles(
            "templates/f1.html",
            "templates/f2.html",
            "templates/f3.html",
        ),
)
```

These are all very small files and, for example, I'd like to make these just strings to make my code easier but how do I do the same type of template inheritance but with strings? All I see is the Parse method, but that only takes 1 string:

```
func (t *Template) Parse(text string) (*Template, error)
```

My strings:

```
f1 := `Hi there {{template "content" .}}`
f2 := `{{define "content"}}bob {{template "content2" .}}{{end}}`
f3 := `{{define "content2"}}ross{{end}}`
```

Not sure how to make these "play" together. (This is a simplified example of what I'm doing and these strings are used in multiple places so doesn't make sense to combine them all to 1).

Comment: Check how it's implemented https://golang.org/src/html/template/template.go?s=12872:12941#L388 In short: 1. Create a template `t`, parse it. 2. Create a second one from the first using `t.New(...)`, parse it. 3. And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```golang
const (
    f1 = `Hi there {{template "content" .}}`
    f2 = `{{define "content"}}bob {{template "content2" .}}{{end}}`
    f3 = `{{define "content2"}}ross{{end}}`
)

func main() {
    t := template.New("test")

    t.Parse(f1)
    t.Parse(f2)
    t.Parse(f3)

    t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
}
```

produces:
`Hi there bob ross`

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MHcHVhUYIKD) version.